# Changing content of {Body}

Tags: html, tumblr

Is it possible to change (customize) the content of [{Body} block](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the description of the single blocks on the site you linket states, the `{body}`-block contains the content of the post, which you can of course not alter in the template for your blog.

You will have to change the content via the editing interface of the tumblr website.